# SVN - See the changes in a branch based upon when it was checked out

Tags: svn

I would like to see the modifications that are associated with a branch.  I can compare it to the current state of the trunk well enough, but the trunk is updated constantly so I am seeing changes outside the scope just that branch.  How can I determine which version of the trunk the branch was based on then do a diff (I like using BeyondCompare, so I need to get both sets of files) to see the modifications.  Is this an easy task and how would I perform this feat?

Thanks and kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `svn log` will show you when the branch was created and where it was copied from (that is, if you did things the RIGHT WAY as explained below). I like to use this command:

```
$ svn log -v -r1:HEAD --stop-on-copy $REPO/branches/$branch_name | head
```

This will list out the branches from youngest to oldest which means you will see the first revision on the top instead of waiting for the whole log to print. The `--stop-on-copy` will print out the beginning of the branch history instead of following the history from the branch where is was copied from. The `-r1:HEAD` prints out in reverse order, and `-v` prints out the copy information which will answer your question. The piping to `head` simply limits the output to the first 10 lines which **should** more than enough:

```
$ svn log -v -r1:HEAD --stopy-on-copy $REPO/branches/1.3 | head
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r160215 | dweintraub | 2013-04-23 13:42:54 -0400 (Tue, 23 Apr 2013) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   A /branches/1.3 (from /trunk:160214)

Created branch from Trunk

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r160325 | rrandive | 2013-04-25 08:03:14 -0400 (Thu, 25 Apr 2013) | 1 line
```

From here, you can see the first release on the 1.3 branch is revision 160,215 and that this was copied from trunk's revision 160,214. This will give you a basis for comparisons. I know some people make a *branch point* tag and then branch from that *branch point* tag:

```
$ svn cp $REPO/trunk $REPO/branch_point/2.4
$ svn cp REPO/branch_point/2.4 $REPO/branches/2.4
```

This gives them a standard way to compare all of the changes on the branch vs. the trunk at the point of the branch:

```
$ svn diff --summarize $REPO/branch_point/2.4 $REPO/trunk  #Changes on trunk since branch
$ svn diff --summarize $REPO/branch_point/2.4 REPO/branches/2.4 #Changes on the branch
```

This way, you don't have to keep going back to the `svn log` to figure out the change list. Remember that `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags` are mere convention. You can define your own, or add to them. For example, you might have a `jenkins_builds` that marks your Jenkins builds. Imagine if Jenkins does this after a successful build:

```
$ svn cp $REPO/trunk $REPO/jenkins_build/$BUILD_NUMBER
```

This makes it easy to diff between the builds:

```
$ svn diff $REPO/jenkins_build/12 $REPO/jenkins_build/56
```

Or, to *tag* a particular Jenkins build as a release:

```
$ svn cp $REPO/jenkins_build/33 $REPO/tags/2.3
```

Comment: Thanks, David. The `svn log...` command allowed to to determine the revision of the trunk the branch was based upon.  I didn't want to create a new branch revision using the `svn cp` command as I just wanted to files copied to a local drive.  So I used `svn co $REPO/trunk@734 trunk734` (where 734 was my particular revision number I needed) to get the files.  Now that I had them to a local drive, I was able to perform a comparison with BC.

Answer (score 2):

you want the --stop-on-copy option to the svn log command, this will print out all changes on your branch until it gets to the first revision it was branched at.

```
svn log --verbose --stop-on-copy .
```

svn diff will show you the changes - you can set it to use beyond compare automatically by setting the [right command in the config](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#svn).

Comment: Thanks,  gbjbaanb.  The link to setting up the 'right command in the config' was very helpful.